# Get a blank new relation from existing ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my project I use `closure_tree` gem and want to write custom method on my `Product` model which returns all parents for given collection.

I tried to write class method:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_closure_tree

  def self.tree_parents
    root_product_ids = []

    all.each do |product|
      root_product_ids << (product.root? ? product.id : product.parent_id)
    end

    Product.where(id: root_product_ids)
  end
 end
```

The returning relation is being merged with the previous, but I need this method to return absolutely new independent `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
»  leaf_product = Product.where(id: 219)
  Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "products"."id" = 219
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Product id: 219, name: ... ]>
»  leaf_product.tree_parents
  Product Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "products"."id" = 219
  Product Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE "products"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "products"."id" = 219 AND "products"."id" IN (1)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

In short I want this method to return ONLY `Product.where(id: root_product_ids)` and do not chain it with `Product.where(id: 219)`.

How do I return a new relation containing only `IN` statement without a statement from a parent relation `WHERE id ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are doing but it sounds like you are looking for the [unscoped](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods.html#method-i-unscoped) method:

```
Product.unscoped.where(id: product_ids)
```